# How to change window title from within Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I change the window title (i.e. text displayed on the browser tab) from within an App Maker app?

I've tried the following with a button onClick ...

```
document.title = 'Hello';
window.parent.document.title = 'Hello2';
window.document.title = 'Hello3';
```

I can retrieve those within the console after setting them, but nothing changes the browser tab text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If App Script doesn't allow to do something explicitly, then most likely it is forbidden. App Script nests web apps within multiple sandboxed iframes and overrides most built-in browser objects. I had a quick look at API reference and haven't found any API to manipulate page title in runtime. The only way to set tile I found in their API is this function:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setTitle(String)

It sets title to the output html that is sent to client. You can achieve the same result in App Maker by simple renaming your app.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a way to do this by including the method setTitle in the doGet function (setting the favicon is a nice addition but not a must):

```
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e.parameter.page) {
    // When no specific page requested, return "home page"
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
.setFaviconUrl('url')
.setTitle('Your Title');
  }
  // else, use page parameter to pick an html file from the script
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page']).evaluate()
.setFaviconUrl('url')
.setTitle('Your Title');
}
```